# Kafka consumer returns empty iterator

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

In my sample program i try to publish a file and try to consume that immediately. But my consumer iterator returns null.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Test**

```
**main(){**

KafkaMessageProducer producer = new KafkaMessageProducer(topic, file);
        producer.generateMessgaes();

        MessageListener listener = new MessageListener(topic);
        listener.start();
}
```

**MessageListener**

```
public void start() {



        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(CoreConstants.THREAD_SIZE));

        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumerConnector
                .createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);

        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CoreConstants.THREAD_SIZE);

        for (KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream : streams) {
            System.out.println("The stream is --"+ stream.iterator().makeNext().topic());
            executor.submit(new ListenerThread(stream));    
        }
        try { // without this wait the subsequent shutdown happens immediately before any messages are delivered
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
        if (consumerConnector != null) {
            consumerConnector.shutdown();
        }
        if (executor != null) {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

**ListenerThread**

```
   public class ListenerThread implements Runnable {
        private KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream;

        public ListenerThread(KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> msgStream) {
            this.stream = msgStream;
            System.out.println("----------" + stream.iterator().makeNext().topic());
        }

public void run() {
        try {

            ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                // MessageAndMetadata<byte[], byte[]> messageAndMetadata =
                // it.makeNext();
                // String topic = messageAndMetadata.topic();
                // byte[] message = messageAndMetadata.message();
                System.out.println("111111111111111111111111111");
                FileProcessor processor = new FileProcessor();
                processor.processFile("LOB_TOPIC", it.next().message());
            }
```

in the above iterator it is not going inside while loop , since the iterator is null. But I'm sure I'm publishing a single message to the same topic and consumer listens to that topic.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am having the same issue. I can see the messages come in the consumer terminal but my app now showing an "empty iterator". It used to work and started to happen all of the sudden. I would appreciate if anyone knows why.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue yesterday. After trying to work with it for a while, I couldn't get it to read from my current topic. So I took following steps

a. Stopped my consumer,

b. stopped the producer,

c. stopped the kafka server
bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh config/zookeeper.properties

d. stopped the zookeeper
bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh config/zookeeper.properties

After that I deleted my topic.
bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test

I also deleted the files that was created by following the "Setting up a multi-broker cluster" but I don't think it created the issue.

a. Started the Zookeeper
b. started kafka
c. started producer and send some messages to Kafka

it started to work again. I am not sure if this will help you or not. But seems like that somehow my producer must have got disconnected from the consumer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know how i overcame this issue..At some point it went away. But i face similar issue now, which i posted in the kafka user mailing list. Subject "If my producer producing, then why the consumer couldn't consume? it stuck @ poll()"